# thread processing a large collection in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, parallel-processing

Okay, It's been a little while since I've really had to utilize a lot of threads dynamically.

Basically the situation is:

I have a large collection from a database query, say excessively, 1 million rows have been returned and stored in a collection of some sort (arraylist, map, etc).  I wanted to be able to take that collection and divide it up between threads, processes, etc. so the work can get done efficiently.  however I don't want to evenly divide the whole collection into different processes.  I want say 10 threads that work on say 30 rows each and when they're done processing what they have they grab more rows from the original collection.

This is the first thing that came to mind to solve this problem.  I'm not sure how that dynamic allocation of the collection to the threads would look like.  I will eventually want to collect all the individual processes results and compile them into another collection that will be for future processing.  I know the query results will be a very large number of rows and thought that dynamically assigning portions to threads initially and as they finish their tasks would be the best way to handle this.

This is a two part question.  One, what would ...say... the pseudo code look like for this? and Two, is this the best way to handle this situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Oh and I'm thinking of working in C# for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't want create more threads than cores in CPU. So 10 threads will mostly too much. Look at this link for some tips and code samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx) (Parallel Linq) is the obvious choice. A simple example from MSDN:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);


// Opt-in to PLINQ with AsParallel 
var evenNums = from num in source.AsParallel()
               where Compute(num) > 0
               select num;
```

This often assumes all the items in your collection and the processing are independent. Another option might be the TPL (Task Parallel Library) for more advanced operations. Here's a nice [raytracer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) example for the TPL.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method responsible for handing out sections of the list, and then make the individual worker threads request a section when they are done with their current one. The manager method would have to be thread-safe but other than that it pretty much builds itself.